# Input "minutes:seconds" format in cell, have Excel convert to seconds and report in same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I'm trying to have Excel convert "mm:ss" input into "ss" format in the same cell.

For example I want the user to enter "1:21" (not time of day, but mm:ss) in Cell A1 and have Excel convert it to seconds and report the solution in Cell A1, the same cell.

I'm assuming this needs to be programmed in VBA, but I don't have enough exposure to make my own program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA code should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    theRow = Target.Row
    theColumn = Target.Column
    Dim section() As String
    theCharacter = ":"
    theValue = Target.Value
    pos = InStr(theValue, theCharacter)
    If pos <> 0 Then
        section() = Split(theValue, theCharacter)
        minutesValue = section(0)
        secondsValue = section(1)
        newValue = (minutesValue * 60) + (secondsValue)
        Target.Value = newValue
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Open VBA / Macros with ALt+ F11, double click on the worksheet and paste the code on the right side.

The cells must be formatted as text, to let the macro find the `:` character.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so so much!